# Scala: How do I work with the constructor params before sending them to super?

Tags: scala, constructor

I'm learning Scala. I want to implement a subclass of `Exception` that gets a name as parameter and builds a message with that name embedded on it. Something similar to this:

```
class InvalidItem(itemName: String) extends Exception(msg: name) {
  def this(itemName)= {
    super("Invalid item: " + itemName)
  }
}
```

In this case, I simply want to prepend `itemName` with `"Invalid item:"` before passing it to the superconstructor. But I can't find the way.

I've tried several similar syntaxes (i.e. replacing `super` by `this`) but kept getting cryptic errors.

What is the correct way of doing this in Scala?

Comment: I know it's kinda off topic but still I would use this opportunity to direct you into the direction of either. In scala it used in many places where exceptions would be found in java. It is an very useful concept IMO. you may have a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193333/using-either-to-process-failures-in-scala-code

Comment: Thanks. I think that Either is a bit too highlevel for me right now. I started with Scala yesterday. I'll make a note to give it a look in the future, when I'm more comfortable with the basics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're actually calling the parent constructor in the `extends` clause, so the following works:

```
class InvalidItem(itemName: String) extends Exception("Invalid item name" + itemName)
```

For a discussion of this syntax and its motivation, see for example [this blog post](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3) by Daniel Spiewak:

> That little bit of extra syntax in the `extends` clause is how you
>   call to a superclass constructor... This may seem just a bit odd at
>   first glance, but actually provides a nice syntactical way to ensure
>   that the call to the super constructor is *always* the first statement
>   in the constructor.  In Java, this is of course compile-checked, but
>   there’s nothing intuitively obvious in the syntax *preventing* you
>   from calling to the super constructor farther down in the
>   implementation.  In Scala, calling the super constructor and calling a
>   superclass method implementation are totally different operations,
>   syntactically.  This leads to a more intuitive flow in understanding
>   why one can be invoked arbitrarily and the other must be called prior
>   to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
class InvalidItem private(val name: String) extends Exception(name)

object InvalidItem{
  def apply(name: String) = new InvalidItem("Invalid item: " + name)
}

object Text extends App{
    val item = InvalidItem("asd")
    println(item.name)
    //Invalid item: asd
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my specific case Travis' answer was simpler, but I'll keep your proposal in mind for when I need more complex treatments.