# scala: how to handle validations in a functional way

Tags: scala, error-handling

I'm developing a method that is supposed to persist an object, if it passes a list of conditions.

If any (or many) condition fail (or any other kind of error appears), a list with the errors should be returned, if everything goes well, a saved entity should be returned.

I was thinking about something like this (it's pseudocode, of course):

```
request.body.asJson.map { json =>
  json.asOpt[Wine].map { wine =>
    wine.save.map { wine => 
      Ok(toJson(wine.update).toString)
    }.getOrElse  { errors => BadRequest(toJson(errors))}
  }.getOrElse    { BadRequest(toJson(Error("Invalid Wine entity")))}
}.getOrElse      { BadRequest(toJson(Error("Expecting JSON data")))}
```

That is, I'd like to treat it like an Option[T], that if any validation fails, instead of returning `None` it gives me the list of errors...

The idea is to return an array of JSON errors...

So the question would be, is this the right way to handle these kind of situation? And what would be the way to accomplish it in Scala?

--

Oops, just posted the question and discovered Either

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Either.html

Anyway, I'd like to know what you think about the chosen approach, and if there's any other better alternative to handle it.

Comment: found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193333/using-either-to-process-failures-in-scala-code

Answer (score 13):

Using scalaz you have `Validation[E, A]`, which is like `Either[E, A]` but has the property that if `E` is a semigroup (meaning things that can be concatenated, like lists) than multiple validated results can be combined in a way that keeps all the errors that occured.

Using Scala 2.10-M6 and Scalaz 7.0.0-M2 for example, where Scalaz has a custom `Either[L, R]` named `\/[L, R]` which is right-biased by default:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

implicit class EitherPimp[E, A](val e: E \/ A) extends AnyVal {
  def vnel: ValidationNEL[E, A] = e.validation.toValidationNEL
}

def parseInt(userInput: String): Throwable \/ Int = ???
def fetchTemperature: Throwable \/ Int = ???
def fetchTweets(count: Int): Throwable \/ List[String] = ???

val res = (fetchTemperature.vnel |@| fetchTweets(5).vnel) { case (temp, tweets) =>
  s"In $temp degrees people tweet ${tweets.size}"
}
```

Here `result` is a `Validation[NonEmptyList[Throwable], String]`, either containing all the errors occured (temp sensor error and/or twitter error <strike>or none</strike>) or the successful message. You can then switch back to `\/` for convenience.

Note: The difference between Either and Validation is mainly that with Validation you can accumulate errors, but cannot `flatMap` to lose the accumulated errors, while with Either you can't (easily) accumulate but can `flatMap` (or in a for-comprehension) and possibly lose all but the first error message.

#### About error hierarchies

I think this might be of interest for you. Regardless of using scalaz/`Either`/`\/`/`Validation`, I experienced that getting started was easy but going forward needs some additional work. The problem is, how do you collect errors from multiple erring functions in a meaningful way? Sure, you can just use `Throwable` or `List[String]` everywhere and have an easy time, but doesn't sound too much usable or interpretable. Imagine getting a list of errors like "child age missing" :: "IO error reading file" :: "division by zero".

So my choice is to create error hierarchies (using ADT-s), just like as one would wrap checked exceptions of Java into hierarchies. For example:

```
object errors {

  object gamestart {
    sealed trait Error
    case class ResourceError(e: errors.resource.Error) extends Error
    case class WordSourceError(e: errors.wordsource.Error) extends Error
  }

  object resource {
    case class Error(e: GdxRuntimeException)
  }

  object wordsource {
    case class Error(e: /*Ugly*/ Any)
  }

}
```

Then when using result of erring functions with different error types, I join them under a relevant parent error type.

```
for {
  wordSource <-
    errors.gamestart.WordSourceError <-:
    errors.wordsource.Error <-:
    wordSourceCreator.doCreateWordSource(mtRandom).catchLeft.unsafePerformIO.toEither

  resources <-
    errors.gamestart.ResourceError <-:
    GameViewResources(layout)

} yield ...
```

Here `f <-: e` maps the function `f` on the left of `e: \/` since `\/` is a Bifunctor. For `se: scala.Either` you might have `se.left.map(f)`.

This may be further improved by providing [shapeless](http://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala) `HListIso`s to be able to draw nice error trees.

**Revisions**

Updated: `(e: \/).vnel` lifts the failure side into a `NonEmptyList` so if we have a failure we have at least one error (was: or none).

Comment: I don't think `Validation` is appropriate for the OP's problem, since in the example one computation (turning JSON into Wine) depends on the result of a previous computation (extracting JSON from a request). So they must be sequenced and will fail-fast, not accumulate errors.

Comment: James: "if any (or many) condition fail (or any other kind of error appear), a list with the errors should be returned" - sounds like a place for `Validation`. Note that `Either` and `Validation` can be mixed on demand, so you can go back to `Either[List[Throwable], A]` after accumulation.

Comment: +1 on the hierarchical error implementation, and +1/0 for the one sitting behind you

Answer (score 4):

If you have `Option` values, and you want to turn them into success/failure values, you can turn an `Option` into an `Either` using the `toLeft` or `toRight` method.

Usually a `Right` represents success, so use `o.toRight("error message")` to turn `Some(value)` into `Right(value)` and `None` into `Left("error message")`.

Unfortunately Scala doesn't recognise this right-bias by default, so you have to jump through a hoop (by calling the `.right` method) in order to neatly compose your `Either`s in a for-comprehension.

```
def requestBodyAsJson: Option[String] = Some("""{"foo":"bar"}""")

def jsonToWine(json: String): Option[Wine] = sys.error("TODO")

val wineOrError: Either[String, Wine] = for {
  body <- requestBodyAsJson.toRight("Expecting JSON Data").right
  wine <- jsonToWine(body).toRight("Invalid Wine entity").right
} yield wine
```

Comment: Note: The upcoming scalaz 7 has `A \/ B` isomorphic to `Either[A,B]` but right-biased: http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala

Answer (score 2):

If you need an empty value, instead of using `Either[A,Option[B]]` you can use lift `Box`, which can have three values:

- `Full` (there is a valid result)
- `Empty` (no result, but no error either)
- `Failure` (an error happened)

`Box` are more flexible than `Either` thanks to a [rich API](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Box). Of course, although they were created for Lift, you can use them in any other framework.

Answer (score 0):

well, this is my attemp using Either

```
def save() = CORSAction { request =>
  request.body.asJson.map { json =>
    json.asOpt[Wine].map { wine =>
      wine.save.fold(
        errors => JsonBadRequest(errors),
        wine => Ok(toJson(wine).toString)
      )
    }.getOrElse     (JsonBadRequest("Invalid Wine entity"))
  }.getOrElse       (JsonBadRequest("Expecting JSON data"))
}
```

And wine.save is like the following:

```
def save(wine: Wine): Either[List[Error],Wine] = {

  val errors = validate(wine)
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    Left(errors)
  } else {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val newId = SQL("""
        insert into wine (
          name, year, grapes, country, region, description, picture
        ) values (
          {name}, {year}, {grapes}, {country}, {region}, {description}, {picture}
        )"""
      ).on(
        'name -> wine.name, 'year -> wine.year, 'grapes -> wine.grapes,
        'country -> wine.country, 'region -> wine.region, 'description -> wine.description,
        'picture -> wine.picture
      ).executeInsert()

      val newWine = for {
        id <- newId;
        wine <- findById(id)
      } yield wine

      newWine.map { wine =>
        Right(wine)
      }.getOrElse {
        Left(List(ValidationError("Could not create wine")))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Validate checks several preconditions. I still have to add a try/catch to catch any db error

I'm still looking for a way to improve the whole thing, it feels much to verbose to my taste...