# How actor should notify sender of errors?

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling, actor, akka

I'm new to the actor model and I wonder how runtime errors should be handled.

Suppose actor catches exception, what should it do then?

I definitely want the sender to be notified of any errors, so, at least sender could log the errors.

Should all the response messages contain `status` field or should there exist `XXXErrorMessage` class for every response message in my application?

What are best practices for error handling in actor model?

Comment: Send back a None, or even better [Left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193333/using-either-to-process-failures-in-scala-code). Alternatively, you may just [let it fail](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.1/scala/fault-tolerance.html)

Comment: om-nom-nom: Good point, just bump up akka version to 2.x: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/fault-tolerance.html

Comment: I would also recommend this read about supervision hierarchy: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/supervision.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should google "erlang supervisor design", since the Actor model was mostly paved in erlang. Then you can apply the described knowledge with Akka actors (which is becoming standard actor lib in Scala 2.10). Also read the above commented akka docs on [supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/supervision.html) and [fault tolerance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/fault-tolerance.html).

Alternatively, you might choose not to use Actors, but [`Future`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/futures.html)s instead, which are easier to compose. Then you will have `Future[Either[E, A]]` types, which you can treat as a combined `EitherT[Future, E, A]` monad type using [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven) + [akkaz](https://github.com/robinp/akkaz) and use it in for comprehensions for example.

I would go with Actors if I expect a lot of failure, need to restart and retry things, having to encapsulate mutable state, etc. If you don't need these, you may fall back to `Future`s and have a better sleep.