# Dealing with multiple options and logging not found scenarios

Tags: scala

When I have multiple Options and I have to process something only when all of them have a value, the `for comprehension` provides a great way to write code

```
for {
  a <- aOption
  b <- bOption
  c <- cOption
  d <- dOption
} yield {...process...}
```

Although this is very useful and elegant and concise way of writing code, I miss the ability to log if say "cOption" got a none value and thus the processing did not happen.

Is there a nice way in the code above, to be able to log the missing value without resorting to nested ifs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a simple function, but it's gonna log only first absence of value inside `Option` (due to sequential nature of `for-comprehension`):

```
def logEmpty[T](opt: Option[T], msgIfNone: String) = {
   if (opt.isEmpty) println(msgIfNone) //or something like logger.warn
   opt
}
```

Usage:

```
for {
  a <- logEmpty(aOption, "Sorry no a")
  b <- logEmpty(bOption, "Sorry no b") 
  c <- logEmpty(cOption, "Sorry no c")
  d <- logEmpty(dOption, "Sorry no d")
} yield {...process...}
```

DSL-like:

```
implicit class LogEmpty[T](opt: Option[T]) {
  def reportEmpty(msg: String) = {
    if (opt.isEmpty) println(msg)
    opt
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
for {
  a <- aOption reportEmpty "Sorry no a"
  b <- bOption reportEmpty "Sorry no b"
  c <- cOption reportEmpty "Sorry no c"
  d <- dOption reportEmpty "Sorry no d"
} yield {a + b + c + d}
```

Example:

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- Some("a") reportEmpty "Sorry no a"
     |   b <- None reportEmpty "Sorry no b"
     |   c <- Some("c") reportEmpty "Sorry no c"
     |   d <- None reportEmpty "Sorry no d"
     | } yield {a + b + c + d}
Sorry no b
res19: Option[String] = None
```

If you need to report more - the best way is to use `Validation` from scalaz or `Validated` from [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/validated.html), so your message about the abscence is gonna be represented as invalid state of `Validated`. You can always convert `Validated` to `Option`.

Solution:

```
import cats._
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.data.Validated._
import cats.implicits._

implicit class RichOption[T](opt: Option[T]) {
  def validOr(msg: String) = 
    opt.map(Valid(_)).getOrElse(Invalid(msg)).toValidatedNel

}
```

Example:

```
val aOption = Some("a")
val bOption: Option[String] = None
val cOption: Option[String] = None

scala> aOption.validOr("no a") |+| bOption.validOr("no b") |+| cOption.validOr("no c")
res12: cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] = Invalid(NonEmptyList(no b, no c))

scala> aOption.validateOr("no a") |+| aOption.validateOr("no a again")
res13: cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] = Valid(aa)
```

I used `|+|` operator assuming concatenation, but you can use applicative builders (or just `zip`) as well in order to implement other operation over option's content:

```
scala> (aOption.validOr("no a") |@| aOption.validOr("no a again")) map {_ + "!" + _}
res18: cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] = Valid(a!a)

scala> (aOption.validOr("no a") |@| bOption.validOr("no b") |@| cOption.validOr("no c")) map {_ + _ + _}
res27: cats.data.Validated[cats.data.NonEmptyList[String],String] = Invalid(NonEmptyList(no b, no c))
```

Both cat's `Xor` and `Validated` are variations of scala's `Either` , but the difference between `Xor` and `Validated` is that `Xor` (and `Either`) is more adopted for "fail-fast" monadic approach (for comprehensions aka do-notation) in contrast to `Validated` that is using applicative approach (which allows `|@|` and `zip`). `flatMap` is considered as sequential operator, `|@|`/`zip` are considered as parallel operator (don't confuse with execution model - it's orthogonal to the nature of operator). You can read more in cats documentation: [Validated](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/validated.html), [Xor](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/xor.html).

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming often works a lot more cleanly if you forgo built-in syntax and DSLs in favor of just doing simple operations on simple data structures:

```
val options = List((aOption, "a"),
                   (bOption, "b"), 
                   (cOption, "c"), 
                   (dOption, "d"))

val undefinedOptions = options filterNot (_._1.isDefined)

if (undefinedOptions.isEmpty)
  println("Process...")
else
  undefinedOptions map {case (_,name) => s"$name is not defined"} foreach println
```

Sometimes monads simplify your code and sometimes they don't.  Don't forget you can treat `Options` like plain old boring objects too.

Comment: just to mention that this approach will not extract options to values. You'll have to do one more step: `val List(a,b,c,d) = options .map(_._1.get)`, which is not much safe - as there is a risk of matching exception (in runtime!!!) if you don't match extractor with `List`'s size. Besides `List` isn't a good structure for heterogeneous data - OP didn't say that all options are of the same type (that you've assumed here) - it might be `aOption: Option[String]`, `bOption: Option[Int]` etc.

Comment: Minor: strictly saying when you're using logging directly (without Writer monad which is unpractical) - it's not functional programming anymore - nothing bad about it as FP isn't best approach for logging and debugging, but still I wouldn't call it "functional", maybe just "scala".

Comment: The `printlns` weren't intended to be representative of a final solution, just a placeholder example.  And no, you don't have a risk of a runtime exception, because you've checked for that condition and the list of `Options` is immutable.  Also for this purpose, it doesn't matter if the `List` is homogenous.  It can be a `List[(Option[Any], String)]` and work just fine.  The `process` step doesn't have to extract them from my list.

Comment: No, `Option[Any]` will not work just fine as you'll have to use `asInstanceOf` to recover types. The `process` step has to (!!!) because they were extracted in original question (that basically was the point of using `for`!!!!). And again you have risk of runtime exception during extraction as you'll have to be sure that size of option's list is same as number of extracted values - or more generally you'll have to "parse" `options` value (which can be changed in the code)

Comment: Just imagine `options = list("a", "b", "c"). val List(a, b, c) = options` (you have to do the last step - that's what `for` is needed for) and someone removed "c" (or `c`) from the list during refactoring - `MatchException`, right? you can imagine any other way of extraction (than pattern matching) - but all of them are gonna have one thing in common - risk of runtime exception

Comment: And again `Option[Any]` is never good for type-safety. Do I really have to prove it?

Comment: And, talking about FP - I meant that the OP's question itself doesn't ask for an FP solution and the problem itself is not related to FP much.

Comment: "list of Options is immutable" - it doesn't mean that developer can't accidentally change it in the code - again, I wasn't talking about immutability and FP, I was talking about type-safety which is a different matter and your solution affects it significantly

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with calculations which may fail and would like to get a reason why one of them failed, you can use an `Either` monad or `Validation` from Scalaz and alike. I've asked such question ([Using Either to process failures in Scala code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193333/using-either-to-process-failures-in-scala-code])), so I advise you to take a look at it, because it has some good answers. I asked it a while ago and the answers were written before Scala 2.10 release where the standard library got another nice monad - `scala.util.Try[T]`, it (quoting the documentation) *represents a computation that may either result in an exception, or return a successfully computed value*.

A scenario when one of the computations fails:

```
scala> for { a <- Try( Some(1).getOrElse(sys.error("a is none")) )
             b <- Try( Option.empty[Int].getOrElse(sys.error("b is none")) ) }
       yield a+b
res1: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: b is none)
```

A scenario when all the computations succeed:

```
scala> for { a <- Try(Some(1).get)
             b <- Try(Some(2).get) }
       yield a+b
res2: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(3)
```

Comment: Thanks. in my case I don't want to raise errors if one of the values was none. I just want to log that value was none and return Option.None as a result.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch it's not about "raising errors", it's more about knowing more information. `Either` may contain either `T` or anything else (e.g. `String` for validation purposes), `Try` may contain `T` or an exception. Thus you may get a formal reason why a computation failed instead of rather cryptic "variable `a` was `None`".

Answer (score 0):

**Using foldLeft**

using `foldLeft` maintain `index` and `result` list so that index can help log and list is the resultant list after retrieving values from options.

note that `process` gives empty list if any of the options is none

```
val options = List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, None, Some(4), None)

 def process[A, B](options: List[Option[A]])(f: (Int, Option[A]) => Option[B]): List[B] = {
  val result =
    options.foldLeft(List.empty[B] -> 0) { (r, c) =>
      val (result, index) = r
      f(index, c).map(result ++ List(_) -> (index + 1)).getOrElse(result -> (index + 1))
    }
  if (result._1.length == options.length) result._1 else List.empty[B]
}


process[Int, Int](options) { (index, current) =>
  current.orElse {
    println(s"$index is none.")
    current
  }
}.foreach(println)
```